# What's wrong with my SQL query with UPDATE and multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE
    `learners`
SET
    `expiration` = '2021-10-15'
WHERE
    `protocol` IS NULL AND `course_id` = 15;
```

I can't figure out why it's not working! Yet the following query returns me records, so they exist:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `learners`
WHERE
    `protocol` IS NULL AND `course_id` = 15;
```

I point out that course_id is a foreign key. Could this have something to do with it?

No errors appear. It simply does not update anything

**SOLVED** https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483346/13568667

Comment: What happens? Any error message, or just no updates?

Comment: If your observations be correct, then the update must be working.

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: @jarlh No errors. It simply does not update anything

Comment: Do you commit the update?

Comment: @jarlh I don't know what you're referring to

Comment: If there is no net change, that is, if your expiration column already has the value '2021-10-15', then the update will report 0 rows affected. It only reports rows affected if you are setting the column to a value different than its current value.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for the clarification, but this is not the case. The `expiration` fields in question are all NULL

Comment: You haven't described how you are running this update. Is it in the mysql client? A query tool like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin? Or is it in an application? If so, what language, Python, PHP, Java, or other?

Comment: @BillKarwin phpMyAdmin. Below I have written the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I didn't expect this behavior, because I know that SQL_SAFE_UPDATES only intervenes when there are no WHERE clauses. Instead in this case it was necessary to act in the following way:

```
SET
    SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE
    `learners`
SET
    `expiration` = '2021-10-15'
WHERE
    `protocol` IS NULL AND `course_id` = 15;
SET
    SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates): _"If this variable is enabled, UPDATE and DELETE statements that do not use a key in the WHERE clause or a LIMIT clause produce an error."_ The columns in your WHERE clause are not key columns. In any case, it should have produced an error, but you said there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your query better use SQL below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `learners`
WHERE
    `protocol` IS NULL AND `course_id` = 15 AND ` expiration` = '2021-10-15'
```

Comment: No record. The update fails